# Unable to rename title of site ,subsite list by CSOM in SharePoint Online if site is created with non-English defaults languages

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I have set up a SharePoint Online site and I have created a provider hosted app. One of the features of the app is to rename  site , subsites and list  and there are times when a site, subsite  and list needs to be renamed, not including renaming the  URL. I can rename  site subsite and list by  CSOM c# code  when share point site created with defaults languages English's  without any problems but when I try to rename site subsite and list if site created with Non-English's defaults languages  nothing will happed and also no error is throwing If I log into SharePoint Online via the browser (using the same user account!) and I use the UI to rename the URL then it works without any problem.

here is the code i am using to rename the site and subsite

var  siteUrl_english = "<defaults language English's URL>";
var  siteUr_nonEnglish = "defaults language non English's URL";

```
     using ( ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext( siteUr_nonEnglish ) )
     
     ctx.Load( ctx.Site );
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            Web oWeb = ctx.Web;
            oWeb.Title = "TitleChnagedFor_Non-English";
            oWeb.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have tried this on both a Microsoft 365 Developer subscription (where I am doing most of my development and testing)

Answer (score 1):

`Title` is actually an internationalized resource. Imagine a property bag holding a value for each locale (I'll put it in JSON for simplicity's sake)

Creation: { en: `My title`, fr: `My title`, ...any: `My title` }
Update: { en: `My NEW TITLE!!!`, fr: `My title`, ...any: `My title` }

To update in another language, here is what google gave me: http://sanderlesage.blogspot.com/2016/03/change-site-title-for-all-languages.html

Comment: Thanks you so much for yours valuable commnet that helps allot to resolve the issue on site level  if passible could you also provide the help regarding list and column title rename  same issue i am facing while renaming list and column for no-english defaults language site;

Comment: As you can see, all of them share the same property: TitleResource. This is the exact same code for each of theses resources