# Unable to rename title of list and column by CSOM in SharePoint Online if site is created with non-English defaults languages

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

i have set up a SharePoint Online site and I have created a provider hosted app. One of the features of the app is to rename list I can rename list by CSOM c# code when share point site created with defaults languages English's without any problems,  but when I try to rename list if site created with Non-English's defaults languages nothing will happed and also no error is throwing If I log into SharePoint Online via the browser (using the same user account) and I use the UI to rename the URL then it works without any problem.

here is the code i am using to rename the list

var siteUrl_english = "<defaults language English's URL>";
var siteUr_nonEnglish = "defaults language non English's URL";

```
 using ( ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext( siteUr_nonEnglish ) )
 
       ctx.Load( ctx.Site );
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        Web oWeb = ctx.Web;
```

List targetList = ctx.Web.GetListUsingPath( ResourcePath.FromDecodedUrl("/sites/dmosite/Lists/liste") );

```
               targetList.Title = " non_english_language";
               targetList.Update();
               ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have tried this on both a Microsoft 365 Developer subscription (where I am doing most of my development and testing)

Comment: The same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169805/unable-to-rename-title-of-site-subsite-list-by-csom-in-sharepoint-online-if-sit